# Write the stdout of a command to a file as well as console in golang

Tags: go

I'm running a shell command in golang using exec.Command(). My requirement is that when I run the command, I should see its stdout on the console, but it should also be written to a file. Is it possible to do it? Can I set set cmd.Stdout to the file and then tail the file?

I set cmd.Stdout to os.Stdout and at the end copied os.Stdout to another file using io.Copy, but it doesn't work.

Comment: [`io.MultiWriter`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#MultiWriter).

Comment: But really, I'd say implementing it in your program is a wrong solution to a non-problem: have the program write to stdout and then pipe its output to the venerable [`tee`](https://manpages.debian.org/1/tee) – like in `./myprogram | tee logfile.log`

Comment: Or use an advanced logger like zap which also supports that out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way

```
func main() {
    logfile := "logfile"
    f, err := os.Create(logfile)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    w := io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, f)

    fmt.Fprintln(w, "Hello, 世界")

    content, err := os.ReadFile(logfile)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Print(string(content))
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/Qfk2AG6a_mB

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd := exec.Command("your commands")
```

cmd's field `Stdout` can be used to specify the process's standard output.

> If either is nil, Run connects the corresponding file descriptor to
> the null device (os.DevNull).
>
> If either is an *os.File, the corresponding output from the process is
> connected directly to that file.
>
> Otherwise, during the execution of the command a separate goroutine
> reads from the process over a pipe and delivers that data to the
> corresponding Writer. In this case, Wait does not complete until the
> goroutine reaches EOF or encounters an error or a nonzero WaitDelay
> expires.
>
> If Stdout and Stderr are the same writer, and have a type that can be
> compared with ==, at most one goroutine at a time will call Write.
>
> Stdout io.Writer

https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/master:src/os/exec/exec.go;l=207

and you can try

```golang
func main() {
    file, err := os.Create("output.txt")
    defer file.Close()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    cmd := exec.Command("commands")

    cmd.Stdout = file

    if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

instead of `cmd.Stdout = file` you can also use as

```golang
cmd.Stdout = io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, file)
```